# What stats do I need to boost when wearing heavy armor?

Tags: dark-souls

I'm playing Dark Souls on Xbox 360 and I'm not too far into the game yet. I chose a warrior and I've leveled up a few times already (mostly strength). I found a guy selling items so I swapped my gear for the chain equivalent. After I did that, I could hardly move or dodge/roll.

What do I need to do to increase my ability to move while wearing these items? My weight shows 27/56 so I don't know why I'm burdened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Endurance determines the amount of equipment that your character can carry while being able to move nimbly. Note that in dark souls you actually have several weight thresholds at 25%, 50%, 100% and >100%. As you approach higher thresholds your characters will move and roll more slowly.

Comment: That's what I figured but stopped playing before increasing it.

Comment: the weight ranges are actually: 0-25, 25-50, 50-100, & 100+ http://darksouls.wiki.fextralife.com/Equip+Load

Comment: I've increased my endurance so that I'm below 50% and I have much better movement. Will I not see another gain until I've below the 25% mark (meaning 112 endurance)?

Comment: That is correct. Of course there are also items which improve your load limit such as Havel's Ring. Otherwise your only other option is to reduce your weight by equipping lighter weapons/armour.

Comment: Yes, kill Havel for big endurance boost